# Finding the heaviest edge in the graph that forms a cycle

Tags: algorithm, recursion, graph, max, cycle

Given an undirected graph, I want an algorithm (in`O(|V|+|E|)`) that will find me the heaviest edge in the graph that forms a cycle. For example, if my graph is as below, and I'll run `DFS(A)`, then the heaviest edge in the graph will be `BC`.
(*) In this problem, I have at most 1 cycle.

[image]

I'm trying to write a modified DFS, that will return the desired heavy edge, but I'm having some trouble.

Because I have at most 1 cycle, I can save the edges in the cycle in an array, and find the maximum edge easily at the end of the run, but I think this answer seems a bit messy, and I'm sure there's a better recursive answer.

Comment: Why not use DFS to find the circle, break it by removing the edge and then run DFS again to find the heaviest?

Comment: @DavidWinder remove what edge? the graph above is just an example, there might be many edges that aren't in the cycle

Comment: correct - but you can simply modify DFS to find one edge in the circle (by the last edge you took while encounter a already visit node) -> if you remove her then you should get graph without circle and from there the problem is simple. just remember to compare the DFS result to the first edge you extract in case you pick the heaviest

Comment: @DavidWinder what will the second dfs visit? as far as I understood from what you said it will still visit the whole graph.

Comment: @noJS - correct again - the second DFS will visit the whole graph - you will have 2*O(|v|+|e|) for entire solution.
Or maybe I don't understood the question...

Comment: @DavidWinder he wants the maximum edge weight of the edges that are in the cycle (not all the graph). unless I'm the one who misunderstood :P

Comment: I guess I misunderstood. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way to solve this is to use a union-find data structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) in a manner similar to Kruskal's MST algorithm:

1. Put each vertex in its own set
2. Iterate through the edges in order of weight.  For each edge, merge the sets of the adjacent vertices if they're not already in the same set.
3. Remember the *last* edge for which you found that its adjacent vertices were *already* in the same set.  That's the one you're looking for.

This works because the *last* and heaviest edge that you visit in any cycle must already have its adjacent vertices connected by edges you visited earlier.

Comment: What will be the time complexity of this algorithm? `O(|E|log|E|)` I guess?

Comment: Yes, because you have to sort the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Tarjan's Strongly Connected Components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

Once you have split your graph into many strongly connected graphs assign a `COMP_ID` to each node which specifies the component ID to which this node belongs (This can be done with a small edit on the algorithm. Define a global integer value which starts at **1**. Every time you pop nodes from the stack they all correspond to the same component, save the value of this variable to the `COMP_ID` of these nodes. When the pop loop ends increment the value of this integer by one).

Now, iterate over all the edges. You have 2 possibilities:

1. If this edge links two nodes from two different components, then this edge can't be the answer, since it can't possibly be a part of a cycle.
2. If this edge links two nodes from the same component, then this edge is a part of some cycle. All you have left to do now is to choose the maximum edge among all the edges of type 2.

The described approach runs in a total complexity of O(**|V|** + **|E|**) because every node and edge corresponds to at most one strongly connected component.

In the graph example you provided `COMP_ID` will be as follows:

- COMP_ID[**A**] = **1**
- COMP_ID[**B**] = **2**
- COMP_ID[**C**] = **2**
- COMP_ID[**D**] = **2**

Edge 10 connects COMP_ID **1** with COMP_ID **2**, thus it can't be the answer. The answer is the maximum among edges {2, 5, 8} since they all connect COMP_ID **1** with it self, thus the answer is **8**

Comment: There is only 1 cycle in the graph so I think your solution is an overkill, isn't it?

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't really notice that the graph contains at most one cycle :p. It's a bit overkill, but should work fine on any graph.